# Compute sum from an array

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, observable

I have an array of floats `weeklyAmounts`, defined in child object `a`. And in parent object `b`, I have an array of object `a`, and need to compute the subtotal of week1 from all children object `a`, and subtotal of week2 from all children object `a`, etc.

My questions:

1. From reading knockout documentation, an observable array is tracked on events like removing, or adding, but not the state change of individual object so in my case, even user changed `week1Amount` from GUI, it won't trigger the computed value. Is that true?
2. It is surprise to me that after changing `week1Amount` from GUI, I didn't see the value changed in viewmodel. Did I missed some thing here?
3. Given what is required, what is the best solution?

My not working code is following:

```
function a(id, name, week1Amount, week2Amount, week3Amount, week4Amount,
week5Amount, week6Amount, week7Amount, week8Amount, week9Amount, week10Amount...) {
var self = this;
self.id = id;
self.name = name;
  self.week1Amount = ko.observable(week1Amount);
  self.week2Amount = ko.observable(week2Amount);
  self.week3Amount = ko.observable(week3Amount);
  self.week4Amount = ko.observable(week4Amount);
  self.week5Amount = ko.observable(week5Amount);
  self.week6Amount = ko.observable(week6Amount);
  self.week7Amount = ko.observable(week7Amount);
  self.week8Amount = ko.observable(week8Amount);
  self.week9Amount = ko.observable(week9Amount);
  self.week10Amount = ko.observable(week10Amount);
  self.week11Amount = ko.observable(week11Amount);
  self.week12Amount = ko.observable(week12Amount);
    };


    function b(bid, bname, as) {
    var self = this;
  self.id= bid;
  self.name = bname;
  self.as = as;
  self.week1Sum = ko.computed(function () {
      var sum = 0.0;
      $(self.as).each(function (index, aItem) {
        sum += aItem.week1Amount();
      });
      return sum;
  });
    //rest of code is omitted for brevity. 
    };

      var objBs = [];

      $(objAs).each(function (index, aItem) {
        var newA = new a(aItem.ID, aItem.Name,  
    aItem.WeeklyAmount[0],aItem.WeeklyAmount[1],aItem.WeeklyAmount[2],aItem.WeeklyAmount[3],
    aItem.WeeklyAmount[4],aItem.WeeklyAmount[5],aItem.WeeklyAmount[6],....);
    objBs.push(newA);
    });

var vmB = new b(1,"someName", objBs);

    ko.applyBindings(vmB, document.getElementById("showBs"));
```

Comment: You never use the function b?

Comment: b is the view model. I modified the code. Thanks,

Comment: Where are you getting objA from?